# Makefile to build library

Tags: beginner, c, library, makefile

I'm starting with make, and I made my first makefile to build my project. I don't know if it's the best way to do it or not, so I share with you my makefile to get your opinion on it:

**Directory structure:**

> ```
> ├── LICENSE
> ├── Makefile
> ├── objs
> │   └── parser.o
> ├── out
> │   ├── libsip.a
> │   └── parser.h
> ├── README.md
> ├── src
> │   ├── parser.c
> │   ├── parser.d
> │   └── parser.h
> └── tests
>     ├── a.out
>     ├── config.ini
>     ├── libsip.a
>     ├── parser.h
>     └── test.c
> ```

**Makefile:**

```c
SHELL = /bin/sh

CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall

SRCSDIR := src
OBJSDIR := objs
OUTDIR := out

SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCSDIR)/*.c) 
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCSDIR)/%.c=$(OBJSDIR)/%.o)


$(OUTDIR)/libsip.a : $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    ar cr -o $@ $^
    cp -f src/parser.h $(OUTDIR)

$(OBJSDIR)/%.o : $(SRCSDIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@  
    $(CC) -MM $< > $(patsubst %.c, %.d, $<) && \
    sed -i \ '1s|^|$(@D)/|' $(patsubst %.c, %.d, $<) 
# use sed to add path to object dependencies

.PHONY : clean 
clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJSDIR) $(OUTDIR)

-include $(SRCS:%.c=%.d)
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use of the naked utilities (`cp, mkdir, sed`, and especially `rm`) is usually frowned upon. It makes your makefile vulnerable to a path attack; aliasing may also result in some strangeness (for example, many distros come with `rm` aliased to `rm -i`); also keep in mind that GNU make works nativly in Windows environment, which lacks those utilities.

  Typically what you do is to define them like `RM := /bin/rm` (conditionally tailoring for all expected platforms), etc and forget all the complications once and forever. Or use autotools.
- `mkdir` fails if the target directory exists. `-mkdir` is a usual practice.
- I prefer to have separate rules for dependencies and objects. Having them combined, `make` builds the `.o` file based on *old* dependencies. You may end up in an inconsistent state.

Comment: thanks, mkdir has the option -p, so it don't return error when it fail.